# cron job on server side

Tags: php, cron

I want to perform a job every day on the server side, for example at 01:00 AM, and I was told that I can use a cron job.

If I execute `crontab cron.txt` for a specific time, let's say 02:00 every day, and then I amend the date in `cron.txt` (to 06:00 for example), do I have to re-execute the `cron.txt` file again?

Comment: http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?crontab+5

Comment: Don't understand the question...

Comment: `cron` will run the statement and end as the process ends. If you want/need to rerun on a schedule, you need to setup `cron` to do that, or (not recommended) find a way to keep the process alive and monitoring the current (to the process) time.

Comment: maybe this would be better here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 4):

Yes, because the list of cron jobs is saved in the `crontab` file.

`crontab cron.txt` replaces the current crontab with the contents of your file. (It doesn't link it, for instance).

Note that **you will erase all other jobs in the file with this command**.

You can see the current contents of your crontab with `crontab -l`.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to make your script executable.

```
$ chmod +x script.php
```

Then move it to `/etc/cron.daily/`.

```
# mv script.php /etc/cron.daily/
```

Also, be sure to add `#!/usr/bin/php` to the script!
The script should now execute once every day, assuming you're on a Linux based operating system.

Comment: Which will only work if you have root access.

Comment: @LeonidShevtsov Yes, the OP didn't specify whether he had root access or not though.

Comment: @LeonidShevtsov This is a site for systems admins. We assume everyone has administrative access to their machines unless they state otherwise.

Comment: @MarkM, question migrated from StackOverflow

Comment: @LeonidShevtsov My mistake, I misread the migration timestamp. Apologies.